# Firebase Instance

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question of logic with Firebase. The following is:
I have chat, like WhatsApp, when I open the window of a room I instantiate the Firebase and the window is real-time, for that I am using to implement ArrayAdapter the Firebase to recover and gives push the messages, it is ok for me .

My problem is in recent conversation list, it still is still no real-time connection to the firebase because of this my doubt logic:

1- I create an instance of Firebase for each row of my ListView Adapter that implements this screen? I do not know if Firebase see this as a good practice, moreover, I would have to create an instance of array Firebase.

2 - Today I create my own chat Rooms as taking a part of TimeMillis to maintain the uniqueness of the names of Rooms. From that, I change this to also use ArrayAdpter and let Firebase create the unique Chars for these rooms and have a single instance in the same way it works in the Chat window with open Room? The problem I see in this is that once the local Instance of Firebase will hear all the real-time updates of all the beds, including those not belonging to the user in question. This is easy to be treated by checking the room that Firebase is pushing for the client belongs to it or not, but I think that a security breach, do not you think?

If anyone has any better suggestions, please tell me.
The structure today my firebase console for this project:

```
{
   chats
        {
           Room1 {},
           Room2 {},
           ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase already has an official example of a chat application https://github.com/firebase/firechat

If you follow their database structure you can accomplish this functionality quite easily. You can look at it [here](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json).

Basically they have `room-messages`, `room-users` and `users` to keep track of users, rooms, and messages. For more questions about how to strucuture data in firebase, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data. With this structure you can listen for updates to an individual room.

Per [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) "it's best to keep your data structure as flat as possible."